# Grab value from text & assign it to a variable

Tags: shell, text, awk, cat

I am working on script that reads battery informations from a system file. 
Simply I need to grab the total battery capacity (3000) from the line MAX_IBAT(mA): 3000; and put it into a variable .
This is the content of the file I am reading from :

```
charging_source: NONE;
charging_enabled: 0;
overload: 0;
Percentage(%): 50;
Percentage_raw(%): 50;
gs_cable_impedance: 0
gs_R_cable_impedance: 0
gs_aicl_result: 0
batt_cycle_first_use: 2017/01/01/12:00:06
batt_cycle_level_raw: 26157;
batt_cycle_overheat(s): 0;
htc_extension: 0x0;
usb_overheat_state: 0;
USB_PWR_TEMP(degree): 304;
ISEN_VALUE_ADC: 228;
ISEN_VALUE: 0;
SOC(%): 27;
VBAT(mV): 3707;
IBAT(mA): 383;
IUSB(mA): 0;
MAX_IBAT(mA): 3000;
MAX_IUSB(mA): 0;
AICL_RESULT: 0
VBUS(uV): 0;
BATT_TEMP: 320;
HEALTH: 1;
BATT_PRESENT(bool): 1;
CHARGE_TYPE: 1;
CHARGE_DONE: 0;
USB_PRESENT: 0;
USB_ONLINE: 0;
CHARGER_TEMP: -1;
CHARGER_TEMP_MAX: 803;
CC_uAh: 889648;
USB_CMD_IL_REG: 0x00;
USBIN_CURRENT_LIMIT_CFG: 0x14;
USBIN_AICL_OPTIONS_CFG: 0xc4;
FAST_CHARGE_CURRENT_CFG: 0x78;
FG_BCL_LMH_STS1: 0x00;
```

What I have tried:

```
awk '/^ +MAX_IBAT(mA): && $NF!=0{print $NF} Input_file
```

Comment: OK... What have you tried so far?

Comment: awk '/^ +MAX_IBAT(mA): && $NF!=0{print $NF} Input_file

Comment: add it to your question, not a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses ": " and ";" as field separators:

```
max_ibat=$(awk -F ': |;' '$1=="MAX_IBAT(mA)" {print $2}' file)
echo "$max_ibat"
```

Output:

```
3000
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` **solution:**

- `-o` print the exact output not the whole line
- -P perl mode
- `(?<=MAX_IBAT\(mA\):\s)` lookbehind assertion to print only numbers that are preceded by the string 'MAX_IBAT(mA): '

**command:**

```
max_ibat=$(grep -oP '(?<=MAX_IBAT\(mA\):\s)\d+' Input_file)
echo "$max_ibat"
```

**Output:**

```
3000
```

`sed` **solution:**

- `-n` silent mode -> do not print by default
- `/^MAX_IBAT(mA):/` process only lines that start by `MAX_IBAT(mA):`
- `/s/[^0-9]//gp` replace all characters that are not numbers by nothing (delete them) and then print with `p`.

**command:**

```
max_ibat=$(sed -n '/^MAX_IBAT(mA):/s/[^0-9]//gp' Input_file)
echo "$max_ibat"
```

**Output:**

```
3000
```